# How to reduceByKey?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using the Spark console in the Cloudera QuickStart VM.

An output file is provided below. It displays the first 20 records. Each record is a combination of a TV channel name and its corresponding count of viewers. There are several hundred records.

The goal is to group this RDD (channel_views) by the TV channel name so that each record is a unique display of the TV channel name along with the sum of its corresponding count of viewers.

```
channel_views = joined_dataset.map(extract_channel_views)
```

Below is the set of codes I'm struggling with to produce the desired output/goal described above

```
def some_function(a,b):
  some_result = a + b
  return some_result

channel_views.reduceByKey(some_function).collect()
```

Output of below code:

```
channel_views.take(20)

[(1038, u'DEF'),  
 (1038, u'CNO'),  
 (1038, u'CNO'),  
 (1038, u'NOX'),  
 (1038, u'MAN'),  
 (1038, u'MAN'),  
 (1038, u'XYZ'),  
 (1038, u'BAT'),  
 (1038, u'CAB'),  
 (1038, u'DEF'),  
 (415, u'DEF'),  
 (415, u'CNO'),  
 (415, u'CNO'),  
 (415, u'NOX'),  
 (415, u'MAN'),  
 (415, u'MAN'),  
 (415, u'XYZ'),  
 (415, u'BAT'),  
 (415, u'CAB'),  
 (415, u'DEF')]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working off of a dataset that is backwards. Use `map` (or change your extract) to swap the tuples from `(count,name)` to `(name, count)`

The `byKey` methods use the first item from the tuple as the key, so you're code will concat strings, keying on count as is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know python so I did this in Scala. You can convert to python. So here you go

```
scala> val input = sc.parallelize(Seq((1038, "DEF"),
     | (1038, "CNO"),
     | (1038, "CNO"),
     | (1038, "NOX"),
     | (1038, "MAN"),
     | (1038, "MAN"),
     | (1038, "XYZ"),
     | (1038, "BAT"),
     | (1038, "CAB"),
     | (1038, "DEF"),
     | (415, "DEF"),
     | (415, "CNO"),
     | (415, "CNO"),
     | (415, "NOX"),
     | (415, "MAN"),
     | (415, "MAN"),
     | (415, "XYZ"),
     | (415, "BAT"),
     | (415, "CAB"),
     | (415, "DEF"))
     | )
input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[12] at parallelize at <console>:22

scala> val data = input.map( v => (v._2,v._1) )
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[13] at map at <console>:24

scala> data.foreach(println)
(BAT,1038)
(DEF,415)
(CNO,415)
(BAT,415)
(CAB,415)
(DEF,415)
(MAN,1038)
(XYZ,1038)
(CNO,1038)
(NOX,1038)
(DEF,1038)
(MAN,1038)
(CNO,415)
(MAN,415)
(CAB,1038)
(XYZ,415)
(NOX,415)
(CNO,1038)
(MAN,415)
(DEF,1038)

scala> val result = data.reduceByKey( (x,y) => x+y)
result: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[14] at reduceByKey at <console>:26

scala> result.foreach(println)
(NOX,1453)
(MAN,2906)
(CNO,2906)
(CAB,1453)
(DEF,2906)
(BAT,1453)
(XYZ,1453)

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pyspark code:

```
for i in channel_views.map(lambda rec: (rec[0], rec[1])).reduceByKey(lambda acc, value: acc+value): print(i)
```